# C Can't type in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I can't even figure how to make this work!
So I coded this thing right heere, and in the part where it asks for input, I can't type anything! please hhelp T_T
What I'm making is a Question & Answer time program where a user can only answer the question within the alotted time limit.
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "engine.h"

void level2(){
 system("cls");


 printf("Level 2 \n\n\n");
 timer();
 if ( time_limit >=0 ) {

      printf("BOO");
        }
 }


int level1() {
char answer;
printf("Hello? \n\n");
scanf("%c",&answer);

time_limit = 20;
timer();



        }
int rules() {
time_limit = 15;
system("cls");
printf(" Game Rules \n\n");
 printf(" 1. You only have 5 seconds to guess what the correct answer for the question! \n");



}
int credits() {
int menu;
printf(" Coded by :  \n");
printf("Lady Dianne Vertucci");

}
int main() {
 int menu;
 printf("TR \n ");
printf("1. Play \n");
 printf("2. Credits \n");
 scanf("%d",&menu);
 switch (menu) {
        case 1:

             level1();

             break;
             case 2:
                  credits();
                  break;
                  default:
                          printf("Please choose a valid option 'tard");
                          break;
        }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

This is the `engine.h`

```
#ifndef _ENGINE_H_
#define _ENGINE_H_

static int time_limit = 0;
extern int time_limit;
static int score = 0;
extern int score;


int timer() {




      while (time_limit !=0) 
       {


         time_limit--;  
       printf("%02d\r",time_limit);

         sleep(1000);   
         }

}

#endif
```

Comment: What is `time_limit`?

Comment: Also tell us about `engine.h` header.

Answer (score 0):

In function `level1()` you should change

```
scanf("%c",&answer);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&answer);
       ^
       |
     space
```

This will eat up the newline character `\n` after entering a char and pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

*Wake up sleepy head*

Your call `sleep(1000)` sleeps for 1000 seconds.  Suspect you want `sleep(1)`.

Also recommend @haccks suggestion to use `" %c"`.

Answer (score -3):

Use 
    flushall(); before scanf

Comment: flushall() and fflush() are defined only for output streams.

Comment: it says undefined reference